# Kasmina's Transmutation vs. Gideon Blackblade

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I were to attach [Kasmina's Transmutation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKasmina%27s%5d%2b%5bTransmutation%5d) to an opponent's [Gideon Blackblade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%20Blackblade%5d) (using [Teferi's Time Twist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%27s%5d%2b%5bTime%5d%2b%5bTwist%5d) to have it ETB on their turn, for example), what would happen?

Kasmina's Transmutation:

> Enchant creature
>
> Enchanted creature loses all abilities and has base power and toughness 1/1.

Relevant bit of Gideon's text:

> As long as it's your turn, Gideon Blackblade is a 4/4 Human Soldier creature with indestructible that's still a planeswalker.

What happens?

1. Gideon stays a vanilla 1/1 creature since he was a creature at the time
2. Gideon loses the ability that makes him a creature, immediately stops being a creature and drops the aura
3. Gideon stays a 1/1 until opponent's turn ends, then stops being a creature and drops the aura

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3.
From the card ruling on gatherer:

> If an effect causes Gideon to lose all abilities during your turn,
>   he’s still a Human Soldier creature and a Gideon planeswalker.

and

> If an Equipment becomes attached to Gideon while he’s a creature,
>   it’ll become unattached during the next upkeep that isn’t yours. The
>   same is true of any Auras that become attached to Gideon that can’t
>   enchant a noncreature planeswalker.

Comment: And if you want to know *why*, the answer is layers.  Briefly, effects that change types are applied before effects that remove abilities, and removing an ability doesn't remove a change it made lower in the layers.